# How to view .docx file from Dired with Cygwin Emacs?

Tags: dired, cygwin

Existing approaches suggest pandoc+markdown or unoconv+Libreoffice and both results are circuitous.
Is there a way to get something close to how PDF pages are rendered with `pdf-tools`?  I have tried shell-command+Explorer but that opens a Word instance and forces me out of Emacs.

What is a way to display an MS Word file in a clean way (image slices ok too) similar to Explorer preview or PDF preview all within an Emacs buffer?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Asking for the "best" way to do something risks getting your question deleted as being primarily opinion-based. Edited to ask for "a way". And is Cygwin Emacs important to your question?

Comment: Yes, my current Emacs/orgmode setup is based on Cygwin (emacs w32) on work laptop (Win 10), highly controlled too.